# GWT/Spring/Hibernate data change events and transactions

Tags: hibernate, spring, events, gwt, transactions

I'm working on an AJAX application using GWT, Spring and Hibernate. I'm keeping some configuration data on the client side, which is almost never changed, but when it is changed, I have to notify all clients about the changes via a data change event using GWTEventService.

All of this is already working, but I noticed a problem concerning transactions. I use Spring's Transaction demarcation annotations on my service objects. Now, if I change data in these objects, the event is thrown and propagated to the clients, but I won't notice if a rollback occurs which would make the propagated data invalid.

What is the best solution to ensure that only current data is send to the client? Should I use programmatic transaction handling and only fire the event if the transaction succeeded? Unfortunatly, this would be a pretty major change, because currently the events are fired by my low level DAOs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use GWTEventService and Spring and Hibernate in a project that I am currently working on. I am not familiar with the Spring demarcation annotations however, but when it comes to GWTEventService being used to broadcast updated data you definitely only want to do that once you know that data is committed and valid.

If you need some help with this maybe post some of your code.